# Determine Parent Component

Tags: delphi, popup, toolbar, parent, owner

We have TToolbarButton(s) on a toolbar, each with it's own associated TPopupMenu. The popup menus are all the same so we would like to have only one menus for all the toolbar buttons. The problem I have is determining which ToolbarButton invoked the popup menu.

I've tried the following, but I keep getting an access violation.

...

```
with (Sender as TPopupMenu) do
  ShowMessage((GetParentComponent as TPopupMenu).Name);
```

...

Any ideas how to get the parent of the popup menu?

Thanks, Pieter.

Comment: Menus don't have parents. You ay want the component *associated* with the menu, but there's no parent-child relationship involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
  with (sender as  TPopupMenu)  do
      ShowMessage(PopupComponent.Name);
```

That should give you the TToolButton that was pressed.

Comment: Unfortunately PopupComponent.Name returns the Toolbar name and not the ToolbuttonName. It works ok on a ListBox. Pieter.